# In Python, is there a more simple way to iterate over two lists of dismilar size?

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I have two lists, and I want to compare them, I generally end up using list comprehension, but move toward for loops when I need to introduce if/else statements or more completed expressions and readability. I've tried lambda expressions, but just not too confident with them.

Below is an example of a general case of when I might use two for loops.

```
rand_array=np.random.randint(1,1000, size=1000)
example_list = [100, 200, 250, 500]
my_list =[]

for i in rand_array:
    for example in example_list:
        if i < example:
            my_list.append(f'less than {example}')
            break
        elif i == example:
            my_list.append(f'is equal to {example}')
            break
        elif i > example_list[-1]:
            my_list.append(f'more than {example_list[-1]}') 
            break

my_list
```

The example looks at a list of random values between 1-1000. I then match their values based on certain characteristics (i.e <100, <200, ...). From this, I can create a new list to describe their characteristics.

The above code does exactly what I want. But is there a more Pythonic way of doing this? And in general a more concise and faster way? Say for example, my list of characteristics is 20 items long. That would be a lot of retyping `my_list.append()` which is mostly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why do you compare `i` against `example` in the first two cases but against `example_list[-1]` in the last? Also, you have only three possible cases: `i < example`, `i == example`, and `i > example`. Why do you expect to have more `.append()` when `example_list` is longer?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ```example_list``` could also be a list of authors or something other than numbers. ```example_list[-1]``` is for any number greater than 500 since they will fail at the first statements.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Please [edit] your question to add example inputs (preferably a small, hardcoded array of 5-6 numbers for `rand_array` instead of a random list and ~3 numbers for `example_list`) and demonstrate what your expected output is.

Comment: Are you looking to see what range `i` falls in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might explore is the `else` clause on `for` loops. I call them `aka nobreak` as the `else` part is executed if there were no `breaks` during the `for`. In this case I think that makes what you were attempting to do slightly cleaner. If this is not what you wanted let me know.

If what you really wanted was to place items into bins, numpy and pandas might be your goto : see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45118/cutting-numbers-into-fixed-buckets

```
import json
import numpy

rand_array = numpy.random.randint(1, 1000, size=1000)
example_list = [100, 200, 250, 500]
my_list =[]
for i in rand_array:
    for example in example_list:
        if i < example:
            my_list.append(f'{i} is less than {example}')
            break
        elif i == example:
            my_list.append(f'{i} is is equal to {example}')
            break
    else:
        my_list.append(f'{i} is more than {example_list[-1]}')

print(json.dumps(my_list, indent=2))
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess my question was just badly formed, and honestly realized I didn't need what I thought. But bins are pretty cool, so I need to look into that more, and I never realized you could initialize an if statement in one loop and end in another!